# Recycle asp.net with httphandler not calling application_end

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httphandler, appdomain

I'm having an issue to recycle an asp.net app which uses an AsyncHttpHandler.
Basically, while the http handler is processing requests the recycling of the asp.net app won't succeed - actually the appdomain won't unload and therefore the application_end event won't get called - but a new application domain will be created - and therefore I will be stuck with 2 application domains - notice that this is mainly happens on http streaming approach.
The problem is described here:
[ASP.net HttpHandler long running ProcessRequest doesn't end on App recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747312/asp-net-httphandler-long-running-processrequest-doesnt-end-on-app-recycle)

And also here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1055587.aspx?detect+when+an+app+domain+is+being+shut+down

I tried to register to AppDomain unload event or to work with the IRegisteredObject solution but with no success.

Any other solutions?